# How to add an image to a slide

Tags: angular, vba, typescript, powerpoint, office-addins

I'm working on a PowerPoint add-in. I want to add an image to a slide.

I'm using the **Angular** framework with **Typescript** for the add-in and generated the add-in using the Yeoman Office generator.

This is the function I call when a button is clicked.

```
async addImage() {
    console.log('addImage')
    
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync("addImage",
      {
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text,
      },
      result => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          console.error(result.error.message);
        }
      }
    );

  }
```

It adds text. I want to replace this so it can add an image instead.

Comment: Show the code, or some other attempts at what you've tried to accomplish. Without that, we have no idea what exactly do you want.

Comment: Can you share  your code and where you are having issue in the code? you can make a minimum working [demo](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer after some hardcore searching. I had to use a base64 string and add it in to the PowerPoint like this:

```
async addImage(imgHTML) {
    console.log('addImage')

    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync('addBase64StringHere', 
      { 
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image, 
      },
      result => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          console.error(result.error.message);
        }
      }
    );

  }
```